# Where is the Migrate UI page?

Tags: 8, migrations

In Drupal 8.2.x there is the new migration UI tool. I've enabled it, but I can't find any link going to any UI page. Back in Drupal 7 when you enabled a module, it would have a configure link next to the module name in the modules page, but Drupal 8 doesn't. How would one find these configure links to the module pages?

Comment: Last I heard, this was being worked on in contrib. Only the core drupal to drupal one has a UI page, but it isn't like the one you are used to with the migrate framework from d7. The route in the routing file provided by migrate_drupal_ui is at '/upgrade'

Comment: jp recently made a blog post about this, which was an interesting read http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2016-11-15/quick-rundown-what-using-drupal-6-8s-migration-ui-feels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Migrate Tools module provides tools for running and managing Drupal 8 migrations.

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools

Answer (score 2):

modules -> migrate UI -> configure.

Press on the gear and you will enter the migration process.

Answer (score 0):

The path for this module's config page is example.com/upgrade.

Comment: That is the path to update Drupal core and/or modules, not the migrate UI.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted, I clicked the gear icon ("Configure") next to Migrate UI in the modules list and it navigated to /upgrade.

Comment: Yup no idea why it was downvoted...